# Excel VBA, countif function

Tags: excel, vba

Before explaining my current problematic I would like to say that I have very little experience with excel and vba; therefore my struggle here may appear to be silly but it is geniune.

I have a column where I have a range of values going from 0 to say 6500. I would like to **count** the number of values that are above 100, 200, 300 ... 6500 and plot the given number vs 100. 200. 300 etc.

On excel, I could simply use the function **countif** function, but I would like to act on the itteration to englobe most of the values and besides, that would be very laborious.

I am thinking of a simple loop that will count the values for each itteration then writting the result on a particular column but I am not sure of how to do that.

Any help or tip would be very welcome.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of data and what result you expect to get? From what I understand CountIf() in excel or it's vba counterpart WorksheetFunction.CountIf() seems the appropriate tool.

Comment: Since it is an itterative countif, I was expecting a cumulative distribution function (logarithmic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inopiae has a great solution to this - pivot table grouped by 100 would probably be the best way to go, but since you're asking about VBA you could do something like this:

```
Sub CreateNumbers()
'this will populate the worksheet with column 1 being numbers 1 - 65535
    Dim topNum&
    topNum = 65535
    Dim rA(topNum, 0)

    For i = LBound(rA) To UBound(rA)
        rA(i, 0) = i
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(topNum + 1, 1)) = rA

End Sub

Sub countifIteration()
'this will output the number based on criteria
    Dim rA
    rA = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    '& dim as long
    Dim Cols&, maxNum&, i&

    'defines maximum number of columns for plotting counts
    maxNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max([a:a])
    Cols = maxNum / 100

    ReDim rA2(1, Cols)
    For i = LBound(rA2, 2) To UBound(rA2, 2)
        rA2(0, i) = CLng(i & "00")
        For j = LBound(rA) To UBound(rA)
            If rA(j, 1) > rA2(0, i) Then rA2(1, i) = rA2(1, i) + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(2, Cols + 3)) = rA2

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I needed, a well commented code where I could get a grasp of the VBA language.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve your problem with a pivot table by having the values grouped by 100.

Comment: I've never seen this option on excel, it could in fact work. Thank you for the tip!